# Begin UIPanGesture Event From A Pressed State At Time Of Instantiation

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

Is there a way to begin a UIPanGestureEvent if the finger is already pressed at the time the object is instantiated?

I have a situation where when a user holds their find on a screen I create a UIView under their finger.

I want them to be able to drag that around and as such I have put a UIPanGestureRecognizer inside the UIView.

Problem is I need to take my finger off and put it back to trigger the UIPanGestureRecognizer to start up. I need it to start from an already pressed state.

Do you know how I can activate a UIPanGesture from an already pressed state i.e. can I get the touch event thats already active at the time of instantiation and pass it along?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it, but the UIPanGestureRecognizer will need to exist already on the view *behind* the view you create (and you will then have to adjust your calculations based on this; not difficult).

The reason is that, under the circumstances you describe, the touch does not belong to the UIView you create - it belongs to the UIView behind it, the one that the user was *originally* touching. And given the nature of iOS touch delivery, you can't readily change that. So it will be simpler to let that view, the actual original touch view, do the processing of this touch.

Comment: Even so this may not be easy. By the time your new view appears, the pan gesture recognizer will have failed in favor of the long press recognizer. It will be interesting to see how you deal with that.

Comment: I think I have a different solution, a little messier, but I will post it when I get it working. Im trying to do a dragOverride call and just pass along the point from the UILongGestureRecognizer that starts it off

Comment: I ended up coding a special drag override that used a UILongGestureRecognizer point, until the user lifts their finger, I use that instead of the UIPanGesture

Answer (score 2):

I think Matt's solution is best so I am going to mark it as correct.

However my code structure wasn't going to allow me to cleanly implement it. Compounding the issue was the object listening was listening for a UILongGestureRecognizer.

So my solution was as follows:

1. Create a callback in my ViewController that would handle the longGestureOverride call
2. Add a callback to the object listening for the longGesture that would call the longGestureOverride callback and pass along the point
3. Manually move the object based on the point passed back
4. If the user lifts their finger, I disable the longGestureOverride callback, and begin using the UIPanGesture inside the new object