# Swift: Long press cancelled by movie playing. How do I persist the long press?

Tags: swift, ios8, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer, long-press

I'm building some functionality similar to SnapChat. Press and hold on a view, it brings up a movie to play, then returns to the main view controller when the movie finishes (currently working), or when the user picks up their finger (not working. That's what this question is about).

My problem lies in the IBAction, when the video comes up, the `UIGestureRecognizerState` changes from `Began` to `Cancelled`.

I'd like for the state to not change until the user lifts their finger, which should register `UIGestureRecognizerState` as `Ended`

Any tips on how to do that would be awesome. Thanks!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var moviePlayer: MPMoviePlayerViewController!

    @IBAction func handleLongPress(recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        println("\(recognizer)")

        if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
            playVideo()
        }

        if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
            self.moviePlayer.moviePlayer.stop()
        }
    }

    func videoHasFinishedPlaying(notification: NSNotification){
        println("Video finished playing")
    }

    func playVideo() {
        // get path and url of movie
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("IMG_8602", ofType:"MOV")
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
        moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerViewController(contentURL: url)
        presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated(moviePlayer)

        // construct the views
        moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)

        // remove controls at top and bottom of video
        moviePlayer.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "videoHasFinishedPlaying:",
            name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification, object: nil)

    }
}
```

**Edit: One possible solution**

So this was a total fluke, but I figured out how to do this in this context.

I simply removed the line `presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated(moviePlayer)` from my `playVideo` function.

Not entirely sure why that worked but it worked for my context.

Comment: I had a 'similiar' issue. Not the same thing but it concerned going from a long gesture to a drag gesture http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27790899/begin-uipangesture-event-from-a-pressed-state-at-time-of-instantiation/27791190#27791190

Comment: It wont answer your question but I will say I found no way to pass the gesture. I think your best bet would be adding a super view with gesture listener and adding sub views BELOW it. And then you micromanage the events from that super view which can handle the one touch (which wont get cancelled when another view gets added on top because now you add it below)

Comment: Thanks for the link @Aggressor. Any way you could show me how to do this in the way that worked for you? Feel free to use my code or just paste in a gist if your own code, I can probably figure it out.

Comment: Would be too much code to paste but Ill post a walk through answer (but it may not be your best option)

Comment: I think a general answer to this question could be really helpful for future people who fall on this post. I'm happy to contribute to it too once I fully wrap my head around this problem and how to fix it. (I'm new-ish to Swift, so this is a brand new concept for me)

Comment: @Aggressor found a solution to this problem, edited my original post above but I'd still love to see your solution

Answer (score 0):

This is ONE possibility but I'm open to better suggestions.

1. Add a 'master view' on top of where you need the touch event
2. Add the gesture recognizer to that view
3. Handle the logic within the gesture as you are now, but the subview that needs to be added needs to be added below the view thats receiving the touch.
4. You can now get the .ended state when the user lifts their finger.

Word of caution. If your view has other touch events make sure this 'master view' is not over top of them because it will intercept those events and hog it for its gesture (unless you set it up to recognize them simultaneously). If thats the case, you can make this 'master view' only a small port of the screen where you need to listen for the touch event without interruption

Comment: Thanks Aggressor. If you could add some code to this answer, I think it could help a lot of people in the future. I'm most interested in #3, adding the subview below the one that receives the touch

Comment: If you need specific help like that I suggest looking through SO or asking another specific question.